# How to modify fields before rendering it to the grid in Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs3

I have to append a value to the data fetched from the store before rendering it to the grid in ExtJs.

Please guide me on achieving the above mentioned functionality.

Currently the grid is populated in the following manner:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.ShowDetails",{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    requires:['MyApp.store.MyStore'],
    store:'MyStore', 
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    selType : 'checkboxmodel', 
    selModel : {
    mode : 'MULTI'
    }, 
    plugins : [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToEdit : 2
     })],

    defaultType: 'textfield',
     columns: [
              {
                  header: 'Userid',
                  width: 150,
                  dataIndex: 'uid',
          editor : 
                {
                    allowBlank : true
                }

              }, 
             ...
```

Comment: Could you explain it more?An example will be useful

Comment: @ankitchaudhary eg. if the Id that is fetched from the store is 'A123', I would like to append a suffix as 'A123D' before showing it in the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible,using the `convert` property in field declaration in **MODEL**

An Example:

```
 {
            name: 'uid',
            type: 'string',
            convert: function (value, record) {
                if (!value)
                    return value+'D';
                else
                    return value;

            }
        },
```

Comment: thnx a lot ankit 4 ur help :)

Comment: If it has solved ur problem..Could you please accept the answer. It will help others also.

Comment: but there is still a problem, the above solution would render modified values in the grid but when the values are updated from the grid to the store, it will still append 'D' with the text.